# difference between java project and java package

Tags: java

If we happen to build a java application using IDE it asks us to create a java project. When we look into the directory structure a folder gets created on the name of the project, similar to a package. So what exactly is the difference between the two. Also can we access a file/method/variable in one project from another project? I am a newbie in java please help me.

Comment: You need to tell us which IDE you are using to get a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A project is an IDE-level grouping; its a set of source files, configurations, assets, ect. that make up a working application.

A package, on the other hand, is a grouping of related classes/source files. It is a way of organizing your code, and also works as the addressing scheme used by Java to find code you are importing.

Comment: So can we access data like classes, methods, variables in one project from another?

Comment: Yes, you can. But projects don't really exist from Java's perspective; it looks for packages and classes, and doesn't know or care what project they're a part of, so long as it can find them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why does the IDE create library folder containing JDK in every project. What exactly is it doing with it?

Comment: When the IDE builds a project (turns the source into a runable program) it needs to know what version of the JDK it should build with, and where it is. Same thing goes for any other libraries or packages your project needs. The library folder is just a convenient, consistent place to store these things.

Answer (score 2):

A "package" is a group of Java classes. All their source files are kept in the same file system directory, and they are marked with the `package` keyword. You use packages to enable the member classes to work closely together (without having to make the necessary methods/fields completely public).

A "project" is something your IDE uses to keep track of your code. This is not something that is part of Java itself.

If and how you can share code between projects depends on your IDE (there are quite a few of them, and they all work differently).

Answer (score 1):

A project contains all necessary things which are needed to run your source code be it  dependent jars ,static files etc and it is a top level directory in your folder structure.

A package on the other hand is a part of project where a particular set of java files(depending upon logic) or may be some other types  files are grouped together to perform a particular type of business task.